# Implementing Firebase Analytics in a swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, firebase-analytics, swift-framework

i'm trying to configure Firebase Analytics with cocoapods in our app.

The app has an architecture like this:

```
App <- App-Framework
```

The app is basically just the **AppDelegate** importing **App-Framework** - which is the whole app.

Then to the problem, i'm doing this in **AppDelegate:**

```swift
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

After this i try to log an event to Analytics in the **App-Framework**  with:

```swift
Analytics.logEvent("testEvent", parameters: [
      "name": "Krister" as NSObject,
        "full_text": "Krister tester" as NSObject
])
```

And the debugger then says:

```
Event not logged. Call +[FIRApp configure]: share_image
```

The framework and the app imports Firebase trough cocoapods and the general Firebase Analytics setup is not missing anything, like the **GoogleServices.plist** and imports.

I tried to implement this in an app with no framework and the events get logged to the **Firebase Console** and **DebugView**.

> The weirdest thing is that the default screen tracking is getting
>   logged, but none of the logEvents().
>
> What to do next?

---

**Solution 1:**

I ran the FirebaseApp.configure() inside **App-Framework**,
trough a method inside of **AppDelegate.**

Comment: FIRApp is old name for FirebaseApp which is still used for objective c. So either you are using an old firebase version, or maybe something to do with swift/objc interpolation?

Comment: The Firebase version is the latest: 6.17.0.

Comment: @KristerMoen Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran the FirebaseApp.configure() inside App-Framework, through a method inside of AppDelegate.